# Newbie: Scala map

Tags: scala

I would like to understand why foobars values below are all 3 and not 1,2,3. Isn't it supposed to map a to 1 etc?

```
val foo = Array(1,2,3) 
val bar = Array("a","b","c")

import scala.collection.mutable.Map  
var foobars = Map[String, Int]()  
for (f <- foo; b <- bar) foobars += (b -> f)

println(foobars)
// Map(b -> 3, a -> 3, c -> 3)
```

Answer (score 8):

No, the code in your question works like a nested loop. It's as if you did this:

```
for (f <- foo) {
  for (b <- bar) {
    foobars += (b -> f)
  }
}
```

What happens: In the first iteration of the outer loop, you assign the first value of `foo` to each key in `bar`. So you'll get: `Map('a' -> 1, 'b' -> 1, 'c' -> 1)`. Then, in the second iteration of the outer loop, you overwrite the entries, ending up with: `Map('a' -> 2, 'b' -> 2, 'c' -> 2)`. And in the third iteration, you overwrite the entries again, so the end result is: `Map('a' -> 3, 'b' -> 3, 'c' -> 3)`.

You can use `zip` to achieve what you want:

```
val foobars = (bar zip foo).toMap
```

Comment: you mean val foobars = (bar zip foo).toMap

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` if you want to pair corresponding elements:

```
foo.zip(bar).toMap
```

The reason this doesn't work is that your `for` comprehension generates the cartesian product of the elements in `foo` and `bar` which you can see with

```
for(f <- foo; b <- bar) yield (f, b)
```

the last three elements are `(3,a), (3,b), (3,c)` which end up over-writing the previous mappings.